How to do HTTPS requests in Ada Web Server?
I am trying to make HTTPS Get requests to websites in Ada web server. I can currently do HTTP requests without issues but HTTPS fails - possibly due to SSL Certificates. I am only using the client portion of the Ada AWS (Ada Web Server) library.
The errors I get are raised PROGRAM_ERROR : SSL not supported. and below that is
raised PROGRAM_ERROR : aws-client.adb:398 finalize/adjust raised exception
I am using AWS.Client.Get(url) and am able to get a response when it's HTTP. For HTTPS, it doesn't work. I can't find any instructions to set SSL up and how would users in future work with my application without having to download a certificate.
Edit UPDATE:
I'm trying to get HTTPS requests working with Ada Web Server (AWS) found at https://github.com/AdaCore/aws/tree/master
I'm on Windows 11 and I don't understand how to make a build of the library and then use it with my project. The library wants me to edit "makefile.conf" and for my use cases - I have to specify XMLADA=True and ssl=openssl. I'm not sure where to add the "Ada_Project_Path" but I made a variable at the top of the conf file which I called that and stored the directory to my GPR file for the project.
I tried downloading MingW32 and Git Bash to use the make command to do "Mingw32-make setup" as the conf file stated but I was unable to build the library - getting an error about "grep not being found". The GCC, Mingw32-make are in my Path and I have checked by doing "--version".
Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to build this library with Windows -  perhaps by using Alire as that is what I originally used for dependencies. I will switch to GPRBuild if that helps.
After I've built the library, do I just use "with "aws"" in my GPR project file to import it - I previously used Alire which handled this for me.
Thanks

The AWS instance might've been compiled / built without SSL support (GnuTLS or OpenSSL / LibreSSL). See also here and here.

@DeeDee Yhh I didn't add any SSL support. I'm a bit unclear on how this works. Currently - I only want to do GET requests to HTTPS links so I thought I'd have to verify the SSL certificates of servers I connect to. If I have to make a self-signed certificate to make these requests, don't users of my program have to as well? Would you be able to elaborate on what SSL support refers to please? Thanks!

@DeeDee I see that in the makefile config, I can specify SSL to be enabled with openssl but how do I build it with alire and make it importable in my project? Do I have to use something different?

AWS uses an external library (e.g., OpenSSL) for communicating over secure connections. It seems that the AWS crate in Alire is being built with OpenSSL support (see here), but a quick search also shows that there are issues with the Alire + AWS + OpenSSL combination (see here. Unfortunately, I can't help you with building AWS using MSYS2 on Windows. You could try re-posting your question on https://forum.ada-lang.io.
